1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` error
I'm a member of the Edgeware SubDAO, and we have developed a faucet app for the Polkadot ecosystem. After the recent runtime upgrade, we have encountered an error on the Westend, Rococo, and Paseo testnets. When initiating a disbursement, we do not receive a transaction hash, and the console shows the following error.
2024-07-19 00:19:07 RPC-CORE: submitExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): Hash:: 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x7098e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xc97d - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h7d22643b0becf577
    2: 0x6f5327 - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction: RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x7098e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0xc97d - <unknown>!core::pan…
1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x7098e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xc97d - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h7d22643b0becf577
    2: 0x6f5327 - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction: RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x7098e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0xc97d - <unknown>!core::pan…

Code snippet:
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider(chain.rpc);
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider, noInitWarn: true });

    await api.isReady;

    const transferAmount = chain.amount * 10 ** chain.nativeCurrency.decimals;
    const faucetBalance = Number((await api.query.system.account(process.env.FAUCET_SUBSTRATE_PUBLIC_KEY!) as AccountInfo).data.free.toString());

    console.log(`${chain.chain}:`, faucetBalance, transferAmount);

    if (faucetBalance > 0 && faucetBalance > transferAmount) {
      const nonce = await api.rpc.system.accountNextIndex(process.env.FAUCET_SUBSTRATE_PUBLIC_KEY!);
      const transfer = api.tx.balances.transferKeepAlive(chain.address, transferAmount.toString());
      const hash = await transfer.signAndSend(loadFaucetAccount().substrateAccount, { nonce: nonce });

      return `${hash}`;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }


I require a solution for this error. Can someone please assist me?
